# Generate new json data after applying math in older json data

Tags: javascript, json

I want to generate new json data from my older json data after applying some maths. I want to apply some simple maths as well as some javascript math functions liek sin,cos to the second series of the json data and get the output in the new json array. I have tried a code for it please take a look.

```html
var data = [{a:1, b:321}, (a:2, b:432), {a:3, b:423}]

jsonObj.result.b.toFixed(4) =  data.jsonObj.b + 100 * math.sin(45);

var newjsonfile = [{data.jsonObj.a, jsonObj.resilt.b}]

console.log(newjsonfile);

// result should be like
// [{a:1, b:0.0265}, (a:2, b:-0.8776), {a:3, b:0.8218}]
```

Comment: You code has multiple syntax errors. First correct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), example:

```js
const data = [
    { a: 1, b: 321 },
    { a: 2, b: 432 },
    { a: 3, b: 423 },
];

const newData = data.map(d => ({ ...d, b: (d.b + 100 * Math.sin(45)).toFixed(4) }));

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply sir. it is working great but can you please tell me how can i apply toFixed(4) function in it.